# How to prepare Windows 8 for video card replacement

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I am going to replace my older NVIDIA Quadro 410 graphics adapter with a slightly more powerful Geforce card (MSI GTX750 Ti).

What are the recommended steps for Windows 8 before and after replacing the video card?

Thanks

Comment: Remove current drivers, remove card, install card, install drivers.

Comment: Or, for the lazy like me: remove old card, insert new card, check drivers set themselves up and text by playing a game or running a quick benchmark. Going from Nvidia to Nvidia is relatively painless.

Comment: @Mokubai, I still have to (re-)install Nvidias driver bundle once again, or is actually the same driver that understands a different model?

Comment: @Matt - You will want to remove the drivers you have installed

Comment: @Matt coming from a Quadro to a Geforce it would be best to reinstall just to make sure, but for most nvidia cards the drivers are unified and so reinstallation is not strictly necessary.

Comment: @Ramhound and @ Mokubai, thanks for your support - that's what I did (removing one driver before installing the other one), and actually they are different installers (size and name) for both models. So, probably it was a good idea. All works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have onboard graphics, the best way to approach this is to remove the old card, uninstall any/all drivers for the old card, install new card, install new drivers.

You can however just swap the cards. Uninstall the driver software and install the new driver software. Windows should be able to use the card at base operating values so you can get the drivers aligned properly.

Comment: when using onboard graphics in between, should I remove old card or old driver first, or it doesn't matter?

Comment: I would remove hardware first, so Windows doesn't attempt to auto install drivers for it when you uninstall them.

Comment: Windows would only attempt to reinstall the drivers after a restart.  Which is the reason you, remove the drivers, then shutdown the system.

Comment: I tell windows not to install the Windows driver automatically but run the driver-bundle from Nvidia, right?

Comment: For best support always use vendor drivers. So yes.

Comment: That' what I did and it went perfectly well: Switch firmware to onboard graphics, booted Windows, uninstalled nvidia driver and software, downloaded new nvidia driver bundle, shutdown, replaced card, booted windows, installed new driver, all good (except I dislike Geforce Experience)